# See if route exists Fat-Free-Framework

Tags: fat-free-framework

I am currently creating a pluggable website, but is there a way to see if a certain route has been made ?
Like this :

- I initiate all plugins
- A plugin want's to know if the home (GET /) has already been taken by another plugin.

How can I verify a route ?
$f3->exists('something'); maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ROUTES` variable contains the list of defined routes indexed by URI.

So to check if a URI has been used, just check if it exists as a key of `ROUTES`:

```php
if (array_key_exists('/',$f3->ROUTES)) {
  // already used
} else {
  // not used
}
```